# C++ how to format a pointer to an array of classes?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I want to read information from a file and put that information in an pointer to an array of classes. it keeps throwing an exception at us->setUserName(name); but if I change it to us[i]->setUserName(name); it says "expression must have pointer type". How can I fix this?

```
    const int SIZE = 100;
    User *us = new User[SIZE];

    input.open("Account.txt", ios::in);

    if (input)
    {
       input >> size;

       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
          us = new User[i];
          getline(input, uName);
          us->setUserName(uName);

          getline(input, password);
          us->setPassword(password);

          getline(input, name);
          us->setName(name);
       }
    else 
       cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
```

here is the user class:

```
    class User
    {
    public:
      User();
      ~User();

      void setName(string);
      string getName();

      void setUserName(string);
      string getUserName();

      void setPassword(string);
      string getPassword();

      void setFollower(vector<User*>*);
      vector<User*>* getFollower();

      void setFollowing(vector<User*>*);
      vector<User*>* getFollowing();

    protected:
      string name;
      string userName;
      string password;

      vector <User*>* followers;
      vector <User*>* following;

  };
```

Comment: `User *us = new User[SIZE];` creates an array of `User` objects. An array of pointers would be `User **us = new User*[SIZE];`.

Comment: why not make us a std::vector, since you are using vector elsewhere

Comment: dont do this ` vector<User*>* getFollowing();` just `std::vector<User*>`. Even better is `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<User>>`. In fact the last one should be your standard way of 'containerizing' objects

Answer (score 4):

```
      us = new User[i];
```

Here you throw away all the arrays you have created by this moment and allocate a new array and thus eventually get **N(O²)** leaked space.

First, remove this line. Next, you might use `us[i]` in the succeeding property settings but since it will be a reference to an array element, not a pointer, you'll need to call its methods via `.`, not `->`.

BTW, in the listing you've provided one brace is missing, the one before `else`.

As a side note, you are using too many plain pointers in your class. You did manage to handle and cleanup them properly, didn't you?

As another side note, it is generally a bad idea to store usernames+passwords as plain text (are passwords hashes here?). :)

Answer (score 1):

```
us = new User[i];
```

Your problem here. This code will create an array has i element, every element is a new object User, and then pointer us will point to this.
I suggest you use vector, it's dynamic array, it's better than a static array with SIZE = 100 in case you are not sure about input file (Account.txt could be contain more than 100 user information)

```
std::vector<User> v;  // create a vector of User

input.open("Account.txt", ios::in);

if (input)
{
    input >> size;
    User user;  // a temporary user
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        getline(input, uName);
        user->setUserName(uName);

        getline(input, password);
        user->setPassword(password);

        getline(input, name);
        user->setName(name);
        v.push_back(user); // push to vector
    }
}
else
    cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
```

Comment: the command "auto user = new User()", this is similar with "User user = new User()"
--> this will create an object of User, and I push this object into vector, it's not a pointer.

Comment: Again, `new User` returns a pointer to User. Next time you try to post an answer to a C++-tagged thread, perhaps you first learn something about C++?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to continue to use an array do this

```
  if (input)
    {
       input >> size;

       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
          getline(input, uName);
          us[i].setUserName(uName);
.....
```